# What are these glowing orbs?

Tags: doom-2016

On certain levels I encounter these glowing orbs in DOOM. <s>I can't pick them up, nor can I interact with them.</s><sup>1</sup> However, they seem tactically placed so I'd guess they do have a purpose.

[image: Glowing orb in DOOM]

<sup>1</sup> As pointed out by [Timmy Jim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/299511/27906) these items *can* be picked up - in my case the inventory for this specific item was full.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is [BFG-9000 ammo](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/819504-doom/73809850).  It took me a while to realize this as well, probably because I didn't have the BFG yet, or my BFG ammo was full when I first encountered one, and so couldn't pick it up.

Do you have the [BFG-9000](http://www.shacknews.com/article/94695/how-to-get-the-bfg-in-doom) yet?  Once you have it, and need ammo, you can pick these up for it.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense! I already forgot I got that gun, because it's not in your standard weapon cycle (gotta press T to use it). Thanks!

Comment: I actually thought they were grenade ammo, but this makes sense. Thanks Timmy.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I believe grenades regenerate overtime and there are no pickups for them.